# Fixing Warning: ssl:connection_info/1: deprecated

Tags: ssl, erlang, migration

I'm migrating a service to a newer version of erlang and I'm trying to fix the following compilation warning:

```
Warning: ssl:connection_info/1: deprecated; use connection_information/[1,2] instead
```

It would have been as simple as just replacing the deprecated call with the new one but I realize `connection_info` in old `ssl` module had a different return format than the new `connection_information` function in the new `ssl` module.

It used to return `{ok, {ProtocolVersion, CipherSuite}}` and the new one just returns `{ok, Result}` where Result is a proplist of various information about the connection.

I need to extract the protocol version and cipher suite from the `Result` to use the new function instead of the old one. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Just like you would from any proplist? `proplists:get_value(protocol, Result)` and `proplists:get_value(cipher_suite, Result)`?

Comment: @Dogbert Oh, good point, didn't realize there is list of keys in the documentation